# node_modules directory is automatically excluded in pycharm 2016.2

Tags: pycharm, node-modules

Pycharm appears to be making some node_modules folders of mine excluded (red and not visible in project tree) without me doing anything.

I've deleted and restored .idea/ folder.

I've add the specific folder as a sources directory inside project structure settings.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon finding this issue in the jetbrains forum, the problem appears to be a Vue plugin.

Removing it fixed the issue.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-22710